# Multiprocessing.Process in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I use this code: (from [here](https://github.com/codebasics/py/blob/master/Multiprocessing/multiprocessing_value_array.py))

```
import multiprocessing

def calc_square(numbers, result):

    for idx, n in enumerate(numbers):
        result[idx] = n*n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [2,3,5]
    result = multiprocessing.Array('i',3)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=calc_square, args=(numbers, result))

    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(result[:])
```

How do I let this loop to run in parallel? For example, on 3 different processes.

Comment: You want each process to process whole array or you want to share elements of array between processes?

Comment: Share between processes. The result would be `[4, 9, 25]`.

Comment: You can take a look on [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool). There's an example which solve exactly same task you're working with.

Comment: I don't find `Shared memory` and `Parallel`

Comment: How does it related to subject?

Comment: Is there a way to share memory and parallelize the loop?